# Facebook Graph API - Pin to top a post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried to figure out how I can pin a post to top with Graph API. Some people said to use property timeline_visibility set to starred but it's not pin the post at the top.

Somebody know how?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible now. This is even not part of UI now. check this out,
https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10204102381228155

Comment: link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a bug at present that Facebook claims to be working on but it's been up since March.  I recommend subscribing to the bug so you know when they've fixed it.

https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/657672685028365/

Once it's fixed it should be able to be done by passing is_pinned with the post data.